# How to increase batch size in Telegraf plugin

Tags: telegraf

I am trying to write a bunch of sensor data into influx from kafka using telegraf. Not sure what the problem is but I keep getting `429 too many requests`. Maybe it is making too many requests since the batch size is too low?

Attached image of error that is occurring.

[image]

Here is the output conf of telegraf

```
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  ## The URLs of the InfluxDB cluster nodes.
  ##
  ## Multiple URLs can be specified for a single cluster, only ONE of the
  ## urls will be written to each interval.
  ##   ex: urls = ["https://us-west-2-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com"]
  urls = ["$INFLUX_HOST"]

  ## Token for authentication.
  token = "$INFLUX_TOKEN"

  ## Organization is the name of the organization you wish to write to; must exist.
  organization = "$INFLUX_ORG"

  ## Destination bucket to write into.
  bucket = "$INFLUX_BUCKET"
```

Is there any configuration that can be added to batch requests and reduce the number?

Comment: The documentation for the Influxv2 output should tell you everything you need to know

Answer (score 1):

All output plugins support [`metric_batch_size`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.26/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#output-plugins)

Comment: even though I specified metric batch size as 10000 it keeps writing for 1000 itself. I'm very confused